# It sounds very strange but why?

Tags: grammar

It seemed to get me stuck, so I couldn't move at all.

Why isn't this like this?

It seemed to have gotten
 me stuck, so I couldn't move at all.

Answer (score 1):

We need a bit more context here to understand the situation at hand. However, I'll explain the difference in general.

Firstly, both sentences sound better with "stick" rather than "stuck".

Your first sentence seems to be a general commentary on a past event (possibly with recurrence if the action was repeated).

> The graphics were terrible. Even a simple movement seemed to make me stick, so I couldn't move at all.

Emphasising recurrence:

> Every time I pressed X it made me stick in the game.

Your second sentence sounds best as a deferred past perfect (commentating on an action more in the past than we currently are commenting on):

> At first it seemed to have made me stick (to the spot), so I couldn't move at all. Then I realised I could move, but I was stuck inside the graphics of the game.

Generally speaking, I think both options seem quite interchangeable, unless you provide me with a more specific context.

Comment: Sounds perfect. Do you have any remaining doubts?